# What can be a possible answer to this asked in the interview?

Tags: c++, algorithm

Q1.) If I have a list of words in a file `abc.txt`, and I have to find out the maximum length word in that file, how will you do it?

Ans) I started with the naive approach, of loading the file and then traversing the file once to find out the maximum length string.

Q2.) Code the solution

Ans) I easily coded the solution that I mentioned.

Q3.) What if the size of the file is increase to 6GB? What data structure will you use then?

Ans) I mentioned a hash map, but I didnt know what to say. That is not the correct answer, I know that. But then, how to do it?

Comment: You might want to show your actual answer to Q2 so we can see which data-structure (if any) you actually used.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to remember all words to find the longest, you just have to remember the longest you found so far. So:

```
std::ifstream in("filename");
std::string longest_word, new_word;

while(in >> new_word) {
  if(new_word.size() > longest_word.size()) {
    longest_word = new_word;
  }
}

std::cout << "The longest word is: " << longest_word << '\n';
```

Then the file can be seven terabyte large for all you care.

Comment: I was thinking about this too, it doesn't make sense for the interviewer to ask about a "data structure"... maybe it was a trick question?

Comment: This algorithm could be improved by storing `new_word.size()` in a separate variable, I think. But I'm not sure, `std::string.size` might be a constant operation.

Comment: @Pimgd it has constant complexity

Comment: I wouldn't call it a trick question. My guess is that the interviewer didn't want to give the answer away -- whether you can come up with alternative solutions when you're already down a certain line of thought is exactly the kind of thing he's interested in. Breaking you out of that line of thought is not in his best interest. As for the algorithm, `std::string::size()` does indeed have constant complexity, so there's nothing to be gained by storing even `longest_word.size()`.

Comment: I feel stupid for suggesting the wrong variable be stored in a variable.

Comment: `struct MaximumWordLength { int length; }` - there's a data structure to use.

Comment: @Wintermute Storing the size in an extra variable might save a lot of space. If you have 4GB RAM and the two longest words are 2.5GB and 2GB long, always keeping the longest word in the memory is bad idea.

Comment: I figured the question was about finding the longest word and not just its length. I also figured that it was about realistic scenarios. :oP

Comment: @BaummitAugen I don't think your interpretation is wrong; it could be read either way. And if you did one, the interviewer would know you could do the other, so at most it would generate a follow-up question that would be easy to answer.

Answer (score -1):

About the question 3. If the memory is not big enough to load the file once. Then you need to split the file. If the file increase to 6G and your computer memory is 1G. Then split your abc.txt file into more than 6 files so that you can load the files into your memory.

How to split the file depends on the word appearance frequency. If the words are random, the you can

```
while(in >> new_word) {
   switch(HASH(new_word)%6){
      case 0:
         //store the new_word into file1
          break;
     ……
      case 6://store the new_word into file6
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Splitting the file is completely unnecessary. The solution is to not load a whole file, ever.